# fread not working in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int virtualAddress, pageNo, frameNo, baseAddress, offset, address, checkValue;
unsigned char basket;
printf("Enter Page Number=\n");
scanf(" %d", &virtualAddress);
pageNo=virtualAddress/256;
offset=virtualAddress%256;
frameNo=pageNo;
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("BACKING_STORE.bin", "rb");
frameNo++;
baseAddress=frameNo*256;
address= baseAddress+offset;
    printf("\tByte=%d\n", address);

        int returnValue=fseek(fp, address,SEEK_SET);
        printf("\treturn value=%d\n", returnValue);
        printf("\tCurrent Position=%ld\n", ftell(fp));
        checkValue=fread(&basket,sizeof(char), 1,fp);
        printf("\tCheckValue=%d\n", checkValue);

printf("\nValue %d=%c ", offset, basket);
printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to map a virtual address to a physical address. I have a file "BACKING_STORE.bin" file that is of size 65,536 bytes so I am trying to get virtual address from user, find page number and offset from it and on the assumption which I have taken 'pageNo=frameNo' I am trying to find base address from it and then after adding offset to it I get the postion in byte to be read from "BACKING_STORE.bin".
But in my case, fread is not working even though my file pointer is at correct position in file. My fread function call returns 0 which means that fread execution is unsuccessful.

Comment: You've not formally checked that the file was opened OK, but since you'd probably crash if it wasn't, you're getting away with it.  You've not printed the values your working with: the values of `virtualAddress`, `pageNo`, `offset`, `baseAddress`, and `address` could all be relevant.  You haven't shown us the actual output you're seeing: what is the value reported by `returnValue` and `ftell(fp)`? I think you should test `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)` followed by `ftell()` to make sure you aren't trying to read from beyond the end of the file.  Showing all the values from a run would help us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out what the error is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char errorString[256];

sprintf(errorString, "%s\n", strerror(ferror(fp)));
printf("%s", errorString);
```

**EDIT**

Perhaps you're at the end of the file:

```
if(feof(fp))
    printf("End of file!\n");
```

Comment: It is printing "success" but it is still not reading the correct contents. Now I'm confused because few times it is printing checkValue as 0 now it is printing it as 1 or is there something wrong in address calculation.

Comment: When I enter virtualAddress=62493 it is showing success and checkValue=0. and the file pointer is not pointing to end of file

Comment: I'm finding baseAddress to calculate physical address in BACKING_STORE.bin file. Size of file is 65536 bytes.

Comment: @FiddlingBits `ferror(fp)` doesn't return an error code, it just returns nonzero if there was an error. (but "success" is what `strerror` returns for error code 0, so there wasn't an error anyway)